# unable to display UTF-8 encoded text in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, amfphp

I am facing a problem to convert text into UTF-8 encoding scheme in Flex. The RPC which gets called is returning Russian text into UTF-8 but the text displayed is the equivalent of that text.

so, How can I convert it into UTF-8?

I am Using Flex.

Thanks.

**MORE INFO ADDED**
Flex expression watcher is  showing  `"ÐÐ²ÐµÐ´Ð¸ÑÐµ ÑÐµÐºÑÑ"` while Flex console is showing `Ð?Ð²ÐµÐ´Ð¸Ñ?Ðµ Ñ?ÐµÐºÑ?Ñ?` for `Введите текст` russian text.

I have put this result on $_SESSION too where it is showing correct in russian form if I change browser encoding to utf-8.

Comment: Did you try `System.useCodePage=true;`?

Comment: @user1875642: its not working either.

Comment: http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/ you can use this site to check Russian encodings. You can also use `ByteArray` to convert between any encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just set the `setCharsetHandler("iconv","UTF-8","UTF-8");` in `gateway.php` in `amfphp`.

This [AMFPHP and MySQL character set](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/amfphp_iconv/page003.php) tutorial helped me. I am not a php-guy. I just got lucky to discover that.

Thanks to all for your precious time.

Comment: Glad to see that my chat helped you find the issue. It is more a issue of amfphp and comunication protocal than a flex issue.

Comment: yes! its an issue of amfphp and communication protocol. But i discovered it later.